# How to execute expression stored in the table, after fetching into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a table which stores date using getdate() function.
For example

```
convert(char(7),dateadd(day,-28,GETDATE()), 120)  + '-01'
```

I've built a stored procedure, where I fetch data from table to variables

```
DECLARE kursor SCROLL CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT file_name_date_from, file_name_date_to
                FROM [dbo].[table]
                ORDER BY id
                OPEN kursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM kursor INTO @f_name_date_from, @f_name_date_to;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

The problem is, when I try to do

```
execute sp_executesql N'select @data', N'@data varchar(200)', @data = @f_name_date_from;
```

I get exactly what was fetched from table, but I want to get calculated date.

The question is how to do set variables @f_name_date_from and @f_name_date_to calculated values based on fetched expressions.

Comment: What is the datatype of `file_name_date_from`. You may have to do the conversion while `fetching`

Comment: A statement: **convert(char(7),dateadd(day,-28,GETDATE()), 120)  + '-01'** does not return date! So, what do you want to calculate?

Comment: it is varchar (200). I think, the problem is, adding ' at the begining and end of fetched string, and that's why it is not treated as expression to execute. For example @f_name_date_from = 'convert(char(7),dateadd(day,-28,GETDATE()), 120)  + '-01''

Comment: Expression: select convert(char(7),dateadd(day,-28,GETDATE()), 120) + '-01' returns a date converted to char. I make conversion because I want to set that value to variable of varchar type

Comment: so you want the data as date datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Example of working code below:

```
DECLARE
      @SQLString            NVARCHAR(200)
     ,@ParmDefinition       NVARCHAR(200)
     ,@f_name_date_to_out VARCHAR(30)
     ,@f_name_date_to VARCHAR (100) = 'convert(char(10),dateadd(day,-28,GETDATE()),120)' -- apostrophes are important here, because after fetching data from table they always appear in variable.
     ,@data_do VARCHAR (30)



SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @DataOUT ='+ @f_name_date_to
        SET @ParmDefinition = '@DataOUT varchar(100) OUTPUT'
        EXECUTE sp_executesql
                    @SQLString,
                    @ParmDefinition,
                    @DataOUT=@f_name_date_to_out OUTPUT
                    SET @data_do = @f_name_date_to_out;

SELECT @data_do
```

Thanks fof help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT cast(file_name_date_from as date), cast(file_name_date_to as date)
FROM [dbo].[table]
ORDER BY id
```

why get all complicated with it?